# how to assign elements of an excel file data to a 2D matrix in Python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd

I want to use the data in an excel sheet as a 2D matrix, but though iterating the extracted data I faced some errors.

I want to load a dataset from excel to python code. I used xlrd library, thought after iterating through the elements, it results an array. While I expected to have a 2-D matrix.

```
import xlrd


workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test1.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

N =sheet.nrows
M =sheet.ncols

mat_d =  [ [0] * N for _ in range(M)]

mat=[]
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        mat.append(sheet.cell(i, j).value)

k = 0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        mat_d[i][j]= mat[k]
        k += 1
```

The code gives me the correct answer here,mat_d[1][1] = mat[79], though when I want to iterate it in a for loop it ends up an error:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Did you try [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import csv

data = []

with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], file), newline='') as dataset:
    reader = csv.reader(dataset)
    for row in reader:
        rowlist = []
        for numeric_string in row:
            value = int(numeric_string)
            rowlist.append(value)

        data.append(rowlist)
```